Changes not propagating to SwiftUI View
I have trouble understanding why certain changes in my data do not propagate to my SwiftUI View.
This is a very minimal set-up to illustrate the issue:
public class Model: ObservableObject
{
   @Published var anArray: [String]

   // Calling this does NOT update the View
   func addItem(item: String) {
      anArray.append(item)
   }
}

public class ViewModel: ObservableObject
{
   @Published var model: Model

   // Calling this updates the View
   func addItem(item: String) {
      model.addItem(item)
   }

   func getItem(index: Int) {
      return model.anArray[index]
   }
}

struct aView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.getItem(index: 0))
        }
    }
}

So when I use the addItem() function on the ViewModel, my View gets updated. But in any situation where anArray in the same instance of the model class gets updated outside of the ViewModel, the View does not update. I would expect that the model property would also publish changes to the referenced object when they happen from outside the ViewModel. But obviously I misunderstand something.
How do I achieve updating the View based on model updates that happen through modifications outside of ViewModel's context?

Note, nesting ObservableObject like you do is not a good idea. With nested ObservableObjects the inner one does not trigger the outer one view to update. You need to manually do that yourself, eg viewModel.objectWillChange.send().
However, if targeting ios17+ use @Observable class, then you can nest those. Have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

Awesome! I'm targeting iOS17+, so using @Observable works. Thanks for the help and reference to the docs.

Since this is SwiftUI you should have View structs with State and Binding for your view data. If you try to use your own view model objects instead you'll run into major issues!
